# Flutter error "The method 'toDouble' was called on null"

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to put flags inside capertino picker. But it is returning error in the terminal, and flag does not showing.

Following is my json, which I am using for capertino picker

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "UAE",
        "url": "https://i.ibb.co/nCJpt4Z/pakistan.png"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Pakistan",
        "url": "https://i.ibb.co/nCJpt4Z/pakistan.png"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "India",
        "url": "https://i.ibb.co/nCJpt4Z/pakistan.png"
    }
]
```

Following script I am trying

```
CupertinoPicker(
  itemExtent: 50, 
  onSelectedItemChanged: (int index){
    setState(() {
      selectedCountryId = snapshot.data[index].id;
    });
  },
  backgroundColor: Colors.white, 
  children: snapshot.data.map<Widget>(
    (row) =>
      _load ? 
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 20.0,
            height: 20.0,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
            child: Image.network(
                'https://i.ibb.co/nCJpt4Z/pakistan.png',
                height: 20.0,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
            )
          ),
          Text(
            row.name, 
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xff41453c),
              fontSize: 16,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600
            )
          )
        ]
      ) :
      Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Text("Loading now...")
        ),
      )
  ).toList()
);
```

Error log:

> The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while resolving an image:
> The method 'toDouble' was called on null.

```
I/flutter ( 9800): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 9800): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while resolving an image:
I/flutter ( 9800): The method 'toDouble' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 9800): Receiver: null
I/flutter ( 9800): Tried calling: toDouble()
I/flutter ( 9800):
I/flutter ( 9800): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 9800): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
I/flutter ( 9800): #1      double.> (dart:core-patch/double.dart:94:31)
I/flutter ( 9800): #2      max (dart:math-patch/math_patch.dart:43:9)
I/flutter ( 9800): #3      _clipOffsetToScrollableRange (package:flutter/src/widgets/list_wheel_scroll_view.dart:364:19)
I/flutter ( 9800): #4      _getItemFromOffset (package:flutter/src/widgets/list_wheel_scroll_view.dart:356:11)
I/flutter ( 9800): #5      _FixedExtentScrollPosition.itemIndex (package:flutter/src/widgets/list_wheel_scroll_view.dart:399:12)
I/flutter ( 9800): #6      _FixedExtentScrollPosition.copyWith (package:flutter/src/widgets/list_wheel_scroll_view.dart:422:36)
I/flutter ( 9800): #7      ScrollPosition.recommendDeferredLoading (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_position.dart:874:7)
I/flutter ( 9800): #8      Scrollable.recommendDeferredLoadingForContext (package:flutter/src/widgets/scrollable.dart:298:28)
I/flutter ( 9800): #9      ScrollAwareImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_aware_image_provider.dart:100:20)
I/flutter ( 9800): #10     ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:333:9)
I/flutter ( 9800): #11     ImageProvider._createErrorHandlerAndKey.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:463:26)
I/flutter ( 9800): #12     SynchronousFuture.then (package:flutter/src/foundation/synchronous_future.dart:41:35)
I/flutter ( 9800): #13     ImageProvider._createErrorHandlerAndKey.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:460:11)
I/flutter ( 9800): #17     ImageProvider._createErrorHandlerAndKey (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:452:16)
I/flutter ( 9800): #18     ImageProvider.resolve (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:330:5)
I/flutter ( 9800): #19     _ImageState._resolveImage (package:flutter/src/widgets/image.dart:1156:16)
I/flutter ( 9800): #20     _ImageState.didChangeDependencies (package:flutter/src/widgets/image.dart:1109:5)
I/flutter ( 9800): #21     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4786:12)
I/flutter ( 9800): #22     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4601:5)
I/flutter ( 9800): ...     Normal element mounting (13 frames)
I/flutter ( 9800): #35     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
I/flutter ( 9800): #36     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6236:32)
I/flutter ( 9800): ...     Normal element mounting (4 frames)
I/flutter ( 9800): #40     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
I/flutter ( 9800): #41     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18)
I/flutter ( 9800): #42     ListWheelElement.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/list_wheel_scroll_view.dart:898:36)
I/flutter ( 9800): #43     ListWheelElement.createChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/list_wheel_scroll_view.dart:874:9)
I/flutter ( 9800): #44     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2683:19)
I/flutter ( 9800): #45     ListWheelElement.createChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/list_wheel_scroll_view.dart:870:11)
I/flutter ( 9800): #46     RenderListWheelViewport._createChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/list_wheel_viewport.dart:634:20)
I/flutter ( 9800): #47     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1883:59)
I/flutter ( 9800): #48     PipelineOwner._enableMutationsToDirtySubtrees (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:915:15)
I/flutter ( 9800): #49     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1883:14)
I/flutter ( 9800): #50     RenderListWheelViewport._createChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/list_wheel_viewport.dart:632:5)
I/flutter ( 9800): #51     RenderListWheelViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/list_wheel_viewport.dart:725:7)
I/flutter ( 9800): #52     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1777:7)
I/flutter ( 9800): #53     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:14)
I/flutter ( 9800): #54     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1777:7)
I/flutter ( 9800): #55     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:14)
I/flutter ( 9800): #56     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1777:7)
I/flutter ( 9800): #57     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:14)
I/flutter ( 9800): #58     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1777:7)
I/flutter ( 9800): #59     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:14)
I/flutter ( 9800): #60     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1777:7)
I/flutter ( 9800): #61     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:14)
I/flutter ( 9800): #62     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1777:7)
I/flutter ( 9800): #63     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:14)
I/flutter ( 9800): #64     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1777:7)
I/flutter ( 9800): #65     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:14)
I/flutter ( 9800): #66     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1777:7)
I/flutter ( 9800): #67     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:14)
I/flutter ( 9800): #68     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1777:7)
I/flutter ( 9800): #69     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:14)
I/flutter ( 9800): #70     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1777:7)
I/flutter ( 9800): #71     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:14)
I/flutter ( 9800): #72     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1777:7)
I/flutter ( 9800): #73     RenderStack.layoutPositionedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:491:11)
I/flutter ( 9800): #74     RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:587:30)
I/flutter ( 9800): #75     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1777:7)
I/flutter ( 9800): #76     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:14)
I/flutter ( 9800): #77     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1777:7)
I/flutter ( 9800): #78     RenderConstrainedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:268:14)
I/flutter ( 9800): #79     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1777:7)
I/flutter ( 9800): #80     RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:768:15)
I/flutter ( 9800): #81     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 9800): #82     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:884:18)
I/flutter ( 9800): #83     RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:436:19)
I/flutter ( 9800): #84     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:914:13)
I/flutter ( 9800): #85     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:302:5)
I/flutter ( 9800): #86     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1117:15)
I/flutter ( 9800): #87     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1055:9)
I/flutter ( 9800): #88     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:971:5)
I/flutter ( 9800): #92     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:251:10)
I/flutter ( 9800): #93     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:209:3)
I/flutter ( 9800): (elided 6 frames from dart:async)
I/flutter ( 9800):
I/flutter ( 9800): Image provider: ScrollAwareImageProvider<dynamic>()
I/flutter ( 9800): Image configuration: ImageConfiguration(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#52353(), devicePixelRatio: 2.6,
I/flutter ( 9800):   locale: en_US, textDirection: TextDirection.ltr, platform: android)
I/flutter ( 9800): Image key: NetworkImage("https://i.ibb.co/nCJpt4Z/pakistan.png", scale: 1.0)
I/flutter ( 9800): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 9800): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'toDouble' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 9800): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'toDouble' was called on null.
```

Comment: what's log after `this was the stack`?

Comment: Include the stack information in the error output. Without that information, we have to blindly guess where the error is happening.

Comment: @TirthPatel you mean, all stuff in terminal?

Comment: Not all, relevant. @Abion47 is right.

Comment: @Abion47 I added screenshot, is that what you want?

Comment: @Abion47 sorry I am new

Comment: @TirthPatel can you please check now

Comment: Please add your error logs as `text`, not images.

Comment: @pkamb I did it, as you instructed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'toDouble' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: toDouble()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58703859/error-nosuchmethoderror-the-method-todouble-was-called-on-null-receiver-nu)

Comment: @pkamb but I don't have any double values

Comment: Are you sure that image loaded correctly?

Comment: @fartem yes dear, you can see code, I am using it in the same way

Comment: It's a bug in flutter... check out this issue : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/61228